# Limit with $\sin x$ and $\log(1+x)$

Tags: limits

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-x}{\log(1+x)-1-2x+e^x}$$

I've tried with equivalents of $\sin(x)=x;  \log(1+x)=x$ and l'Hopital, can someone give me hints?

Comment: try $$ sinx=x- \frac{x^3}{3!}\\e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+..\\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use l'Hopital several times.

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x -x}{\ln (x+1)-1-2x+e^x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-1}{\frac{1}{x+1}-2+e^x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\sin x}{-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}+e^x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\cos x}{\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}+e^x}\\&=-\frac 13.\end{align}$$